# Python Error Reporting

Tags: python, logging, runtime-error

I've recently started development with Python, and I've noticed that whenever my code generates an runtime error, the details flash into the output for a split-second and then the program closes. Is there a way to either stop the program from closing when this happens or to log the errors into a textfile?

Comment: Run your python programs from the command-line with `python filename.py`.

Comment: Log the errors with `python filename.py > output.txt`.

Comment: Or use any Python IDE, e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: Note that just `filename.py` should work, too.

Comment: @pp_ only for unix systems. Under Windows this is no working.

Comment: @bastelflp It works for Windows, too.

Comment: @pp_ Well, not out of the box (at least at my system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the suggestions in the comments which all work well, you can always (and should always) use the `logging` module. You can set up basic logging facilities quickly, and it allows to change the level of information displayed to the user.

(From the ['Python Module of The Week' website](https://pymotw.com/2/logging/))

```
import logging

LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_example.out'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')

f = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'rt')
try:
    body = f.read()
finally:
    f.close()

print 'FILE:'
print body
```

You can log to different levels (i.e. info, warning, debug, error) and have those displayed while the code is running, or hiding them, by setting the level arg of `logging.basicConfig()`.

[How To Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

[Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

Comment: Of course using the logging module for scripts with a few lines may seem overkill; it will still work, but dumping it to file with `>` may serve your needs better if you're just prototyping. For modules and programs, `logging` is a must.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the above comments, you can:

- run your file from the command-line with `python filename.py`
- log the errors to any text file with `python filename.py > output.txt`
- use a Python [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

All of the above should help you reading the error stack trace.